# What is this structured comment and what is "updated" field for?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am working on Python in Eclipse + PyDev. When I create a new module from "Module: CLI (argparse)" template, Eclipse creates the following comment block in the beginning of the file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
'''
packagename.newfile -- shortdesc

packagename.newfile is a description

It defines classes_and_methods

@author:     user_name

@copyright:  2015 organization_name. All rights reserved.

@license:    license

@contact:    user_email
@deffield    updated: Updated
'''
```

It appears to have some kind of structure, I guess it's parsed by something? I have a few questions:

- How is this type of comment structure called and by what programs is it used?
- How do I include a multiline apache license 2.0 notice under `@license`?
- What is `updated` field for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Python documentation in this form is adhering to the Epydoc standard.

http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-fields.html shows details of all of the fields that you've listed above. This file can then be parsed by Epydoc and documentation created from that.

This following example shows that multiline documentation is allowed:

```
def example():
    """
    @param x: This is a description of
        the parameter x to a function.
        Note that the description is
        indented four spaces.
    @type x: This is a description of
        x's type.
    @return: This is a description of
        the function's return value.

        It contains two paragraphs.
    """
    #[...]
```

This was sourced from http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epydoc.html#fields

The `updated` part is showing the ability to add in any @style annotation. See http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epydoc.html#adding-new-fields.

So `@deffield    updated: Updated` means that there's a new annotation `@updated`. This would be used as follows

```
"""
@updated 17/02/2015
"""
```

This would then be rendered into the HTML created from Epydoc.

Comment: I wouldn't say "most" docs are in this format. I've been programming Python for years and have never used it, and almost never encounter it in libraries.

Comment: That's very true. I guess i should have written "Most docs (in this form) are adhering to Epydoc standards"